# Does google play provide any API when there is a new version of app

Tags: android, api, google-play

I know Android shows a notification on new version of app , but want to explicitly show the user when there is new update 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should implement your own service which keeps checking a server for the latest version of your app. If the device's installed version is lower than the version mentioned in the server you could prompt the user that there is an update available.

Comment: That's the only option. :)